# Azure Entity Framework Code First Migration after reactivation of subscription

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

Good day...

I have a Web application and SQL Server database in Azure, that has been working great, designed from the very start to use Code First EF 6.1.3 and Azure.

Microsoft recently deactivated my Azure account, but I got them to re-activate it.

After it was re-activated, though, on first load of the application, it attempted to run Code First Migrations again.  All of the tables are still out there in the database, including the MigrationHistory table, so I cannot figure out why it is attempting to run all migrations again.

The table that it breaks on is AspNetRoles, which is in the very first migration file listed in the MigrationHistory table.

Any ideas what I need to do to get it to see that they are already applied?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check on a local db copy if the problem can be reproduces under debugger with local db access?

Comment: After seeing your suggestion, I looked into the database tables to see if there was any difference, anything I could tweak, but I found nothing that I could change.  The _MigrationHistory table has all the same rows on it.  I did change one of the row values locally and saw a completely different error, but I put it back and everything worked as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, but we could not determine the reason for the disconnect.  I got in contact with Microsoft Support and they helped me to get up and running again.  In order to restore the functionality of the system, and keep the existing data,

We:

1. Disabled migrations
2. Removed all evidence of migrations
3. Re-enabled migrations
4. Created an initial migration with the -IgnoreChanges flag
5. Performed an update-database

This got the migrations back in sync.

As explained to me, this was basically using a database-first EF method and from now on I will continue to use Code-first methods.